# Interpolation of $L^p$ spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, measure-theory, interpolation-spaces

Let $\Omega_x$ and $\Omega_y$ be sets of finite Lebesgue measure.

We can then look at the space $X_1:=L^2(\Omega_x \times \Omega_y).$

This space is contained in the larger space

$$X_0:=L^2(\Omega_x; L^1(\Omega_y)).$$

On the other hand, the space $$X_2:=L^2(\Omega_y;L^{\infty}(\Omega_x))$$ is smaller than $X_1.$

Altogether

$$X_2 \subset X_1 \subset X_0.$$

I am wondering whether we can interpolate the canonical norm on $X_1$ just in terms of the canonical norms on $X_0$ and $X_2$ such that convergence in $X_0$ and boundedness in $X_2$ implies convergence in $X_1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Notice that since you assumed finiteness of the $\Omega_x$ measure, we can restrict to looking at functions that are constant in $x$.

Let $\Omega_y = [0,1]$ for example, and take $\chi_n(y) = \sqrt{n} \mathbb{1}_{[0,1/n]}$.

The sequence of functions $\chi_n \overset{L^1}{\longrightarrow} 0$, and is bounded in $L^2$. But do not converge in $L^2$.

Now extend the function so they are independent of $x$, and you have a counterexample for your triple of spaces.

Comment: The main problem is that you used an $L^2$ endpoint in $X_2$. By Holder's inequality you can interpolate $L^2_{x,y}$ by $L^2_x L^1_y$ and $L^2_x L^p_y$ for any $p > 2$. Finiteness of measure and Minkowski's inequality allows you to bound $L^2_x L^p_y$ by $L^p_y L^\infty_x$. So all you need is boundedness in something just a tiny bit stronger than $L^2_y L^\infty_x$ and you are set.